# how to get the uuid of ios application programmatically?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, uuid

How do I get the UUID of an iOS application programmatically?

I know we can use command `dwarfdump` to get the uuid of an iOS application. For example:

```
Downloads user$ dwarfdump --uuid ./Payload/sdd.app/sdd  UUID: 9D9E0AD2-9925-3CD1-B190-3F9E1EB3A774 (armv7) ./Payload/sdd.app/sdd UUID: E5213B30-5E3B-3BA5-9097-750385F2058B (arm64) ./Payload/sdd.app/sdd
```

Is there any code can get the UUID in Objective-C or C++?

I want to write this string to log files.

I have searched this on Google, but couldn't find anything. Most of the results are about getting the device's ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`-(NSString*) uuid {

    CFUUIDRef puuid = CFUUIDCreate( nil );

    CFStringRef uuidString = CFUUIDCreateString( nil, puuid );

    NSString * result = (NSString *)CFStringCreateCopy( NULL, uuidString);

    CFRelease(puuid);

    CFRelease(uuidString);

    return [result autorelease];

}`

you can call this method when the application runs of the first time, and then store it in your phone.